# Angular Apply matSort accross multiple Tabs in matTabGroup

Tags: angular, angular-material, mat-tab

I have a requirement where am displaying the data from a single across multiple tabs in a page. I want to allow users to both filter and sort on any of the tabs. I have been able to filter, but so far I can only get the sort to work on one tab at a time. Is there a way to have one sort work across multiple tabs. I am including some brief Snippets that show what I am trying to do.

.ts file

```
export class NcsatsHomeComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);
  dataSource2 = new MatTableDataSource<any>([]);

  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;    
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  displayedColumns: string[] = ['CauseEffect', 'nonconSys', 'nonconRec', 'partNumber', 'partName']
  displayedColumns1: string[] = ['CauseEffect1', 'nonconSys1', 'nonconRec1', 'partNumber1', 'partName1']
  displayedColumns2: string[] = ['CauseEffect', 'nonconSys', 'nonconRec', 'discrepancyShort', 'dispositionShort']
  displayedColumns3: string[] = ['CauseEffect1', 'nonconSys1', 'nonconRec1', 'discrepancyShort1', 'dispositionShort1']

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getData();
  }

  getData(){
    this.loggedIn = this.authenticationService.loginNeeded();
    console.log('login check', this.loggedIn);
    if(this.loggedIn){
      this.isLoading = true
      this.isempty = false;
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.repoService.getEntries(0,1000).subscribe(largeDataSet => {
          this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
          this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
          this.dataSource.data = largeDataSet;
          this.dataSource.data.forEach(element => {Object.keys(element).forEach(k => element[k] = element[k] === null ? '' : element[k])});
          console.log(this.dataSource.data);
          this.dataSource2.data = this.dataSource.data;
          this.isLoading = false;
          this.runAllChanges();
        })
      })
    } else {
      this.router.navigateByUrl('/');
    }

  }
}
```

.html file

```
<mat-tab-group mat-align-tabs="center" [selectedIndex]="mytab">
    <!-- <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort> -->
    <mat-tab label="Part Identification" >
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="CauseEffect">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 180px;padding-right: 15px;"> Cause/Effect </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nonconSys}}{{row.nonconRec}}{{row.tagRev}}{{row.status}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="nonconSys">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 60px;padding-right: 15px;"> System </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nonconSys}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="nonconRec">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 100px;padding-right: 15px;"> Noncon Rec </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nonconRec}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="partNumber">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 150px;padding-right: 15px;"> Primary P/N </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
                    <div *ngIf = "!selection.isSelected(row)">
                        {{row.partNumber}}
                      </div>
                      <div *ngIf = "selection.isSelected(row)">
                        <mat-form-field style="width: 150px;">
                            <input type="text" matInput #input [value]="row.partNumber" [(ngModel)]="row.partNumber" (input)="sendUpdateInfo(row)"
                            (ngModelChange)="row.partNumber = $event.toUpperCase()">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="partName">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 200px;padding-right: 15px;"> Primary Part Name </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> 
                    <div *ngIf = "!selection.isSelected(row)">
                        {{row.partName}}
                      </div>
                      <div *ngIf = "selection.isSelected(row)" >
                        <mat-form-field style="width: 200px">
                            <input type="text" matInput #input [value]="row.partName" [(ngModel)]="row.partName" (input)="sendUpdateInfo(row)"
                            (ngModelChange)="row.partName = $event.toUpperCase()">
                        </mat-form-field>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="CauseEffect1">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 180px;padding-right: 15px;"> 
                </th>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="nonconSys1">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 60px;padding-right: 15px;"> 
                    <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never"  style="width: 60px;">
                        <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
                        <input  matInput (keyup)="nonconSysFilterFunc()" [(ngModel)]="nonconSysFilter" [disabled]="isLoading">
                    </mat-form-field> 
                </th>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="nonconRec1">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 100px;padding-right: 15px;"> 
                    <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never"  style="width: 100px;">
                        <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
                        <input  matInput (keyup)="nonconRecFilterFunc()" [(ngModel)]="nonconRecFilter" [disabled]="isLoading">
                    </mat-form-field> 
                </th>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="partNumber1">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 150px;padding-right: 15px;"> 
                    <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never"  style="width: 150px;">
                        <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
                        <input  matInput (keyup)="partNumberFilterFunc()" [(ngModel)]="partNumberFilter" [disabled]="isLoading">
                    </mat-form-field> 
                </th>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="partName1">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 200px;padding-right: 15px;"> 
                    <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never"  style="width: 200px;">
                        <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
                        <input  matInput (keyup)="partNameFilterFunc()" [(ngModel)]="partNameFilter" [disabled]="isLoading">
                    </mat-form-field> 
                </th>
            </ng-container>
        </table>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Discrepancy" >
        <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
            <ng-container matColumnDef="CauseEffect">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 180px;padding-right: 15px;"> Cause/Effect </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nonconSys}}{{row.nonconRec}}{{row.tagRev}}{{row.status}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="nonconSys">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 60px;padding-right: 15px;"> System </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nonconSys}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="nonconRec">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 100px;padding-right: 15px;"> Noncon Rec </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.nonconRec}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="discrepancyShort">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 260px;padding-right: 15px;"> Discrepancy </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.discrepancyShort}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="dispositionShort">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header style="width: 260px;padding-right: 15px;"> Disposition </th>
                <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row"> {{row.dispositionShort}} </td>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="CauseEffect1">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 180px;padding-right: 15px;"> 
                </th>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="nonconSys1">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 60px;padding-right: 15px;"> 
                    <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never"  style="width: 60px;">
                        <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
                        <input  matInput (keyup)="nonconSysFilterFunc()" [(ngModel)]="nonconSysFilter" [disabled]="isLoading">
                    </mat-form-field> 
                </th>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="nonconRec1">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 100px;padding-right: 15px;"> 
                    <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never"  style="width: 100px;">
                        <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
                        <input  matInput (keyup)="nonconRecFilterFunc()" [(ngModel)]="nonconRecFilter" [disabled]="isLoading">
                    </mat-form-field> 
                </th>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="discrepancyShort1">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 260px;padding-right: 15px;"> 
                    <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never"  style="width: 260px;">
                        <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
                        <input  matInput (keyup)="discrepancyShortFilterFunc()" [(ngModel)]="discrepancyShortFilter" [disabled]="isLoading">
                    </mat-form-field> 
                </th>
            </ng-container>

            <ng-container matColumnDef="dispositionShort1">
                <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef style="width: 260px;padding-right: 15px;"> 
                    <mat-form-field class="filter" floatLabel="never"  style="width: 260px;">
                        <mat-label>Filter</mat-label>
                        <input  matInput (keyup)="dispositionShortFilterFunc()" [(ngModel)]="dispositionShortFilter" [disabled]="isLoading">
                    </mat-form-field> 
                </th>
            </ng-container>
        </table>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```